# What does different "basis" mean

Tags: quantum-entanglement

I am reading about quantum cryptography BB84 method at the moment.

It talks about two basis: V/H and ${V_{45}/H_{45}}$ where the light is sent through a polariser at 45 degrees. These are then the two basis that Alice and Bob can choose to measure.

But what do they mean by the term basis, does it mean that V/H is orthonormal to ${V_{45}/H_{45}}$ and thus each are a basis - this term i've not seen used so far until now so i am not familiar with what the term means? Or does it have some other meaning?

Comment: A reference to the material would be nice, but it looks like they mean simply a different reference frame: rotating the x and y axis of your measurement apparatus by 45 degrees, for example.

Comment: So would any angle of choice there for be its own basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V and H stand for vertical and horizontal polarisation states. These two quantum states are orthogonal to one another. This means that if you create a stream of photons in the V state (using a polaroid filter orientated vertically) and then filter them through a horizontally orientated filter, none of the photons will pass through, because V and H states are mutually exclusive.

A photon with some other angle of polarisation, between vertical and horizontal, can always be described as a superposition of V and H states. This is why we call the V/H set a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)). The term comes from the area of mathematics called linear algebra, which is the mathematics of vector spaces.

In particular, $V_{45}$ and $H_{45}$ polarisation states at $45^o$ to the horizontal and vertical, can be expressed as

$V_{45}=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \left( V+H \right)$

$H_{45}=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \left( V-H \right)$

Notice that $V_{45}$ and $H_{45}$ are orthogonal to one another, but neither one is orthogonal to V or H.

But we could also express V and H as superposition of states $V_{45}$ and $H_{45}$. So $V_{45}$ and $H_{45}$ are another alternative basis for describing polarisation states. And there is nothing special about the angle $45^o$. You can use any two orthogonal polarisation states as a basis for the space of all polarisation states.